# Shopify Theme Export, how long does it take to receive

Tags: shopify

I'm currently making updates to a theme for a Shopify site. I don't want to make updates to the theme on the live Shopify store.

My plan was to download the theme, and products, create my own "testing" store, where I will make and test updates. Once the updates have been tested I will move the theme back to the live site.

Shopify emails these assets to the accounts email address. Which doesn't seem like it would be an issue, but it's been hours since I submitted the request to download and no email has been received.

Does anyone know how long this usually takes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It usually takes a matter of minutes for them to send the theme to an email.